# Theming forms. Form-element

Tags: theming, forms, 8

Please, help. Is it possible implement different templates for form-element.html.twig? For form 'user-form' one template, and for other forms second template.

Comment: I'm running the same problem. In my case all fields in 'user-form' are label_display after, to solve this, I changed them in `template_preprocess_form_element` by fields names.

Comment: Could you give example how you use did it?

Answer (score 2):

As you requested, this is an example how I did using field names.

**In your .theme file:**

```
function THEME_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  //This is a list of fields in contact form
  $showAfter = array('name', 'mail', 'subject[0][value]', 'message[0][value]');
  if (in_array($variables['name'], $showAfter)) {
    //If is one, I change here how to display instead using different twig file
    $variables['element']['#title_display'] = 'after';
    $variables['label_display'] = 'after';
  }
}
```

Now, if you want use different twig file for each field name use this...

**.theme file**

```
function THEME_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#name'])) {
    //Name can be a string like this, 'subject[0][value]'.
    //When this happen, I just get 'subject'.
    $suggestions[] = 'form_element__' . explode("[", $variables['element']['#name'])[0];
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML appear something like this:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * form-element--subject.html.twig
   x form-element.html.twig
-->
```

**Note:**
The main problem is how you get form_id in `preprocess` or `theme_suggestions` (form_element Hook), I didn't find a way to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

I found out another way to solve my problem. In form_alter function i added this code: 

$form['custom_field']['theme_wrapper'] = 'form-element-custom.html.twig'; 

And, its help me.